# how to get Listview Selected Item

Tags: vb.net, listview, selectedindex

I have a lisview that I have created that loads information into the program from selected files. I am now trying to add in a search button to the information typed in so that it highlights (selects) the line of code that information is found in (Entire line for both columns) Multiselect is turned on.

The part I am stuck with is if it was a normal listbox I would use selectedindex but with Listview this method does not seem to work and only has selectedIndexCollection or selected items.

If I try something like these they dont seem to work and want more information added

```
List.SelectedIndexCollection = Lines.text
List.SelectedItems = Lines.text
```

Edit from Comments:

```
Private Sub Search_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
     Handles Search.Click 



     Do Until List.FocusedItem.text = lines.text
        List.FocusedItem = List.Items(0) +1
     Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: code illustrating the problem is pretty much required or these kinds of questions get closed.

Comment: Technically I did post my two lines of code that I tried but not really sure of any other methods to try to use for this examples being: List.SelectedIndexCollection = Lines.text 
and List.SelectedItems = Lines.text

Comment: sorry, unformatted as it was, it was nonsense; what is `Lines`?  if you are trying to **set** selected items, you need to loop thru each LVI, test it against something and set it as selected if it passes.  what are you searching, the Item or SubItem?  or are you trying to use the LV as the search term provider?

Comment: Lines is the name of my textbox
I am searching the subitem in my LV but to highlight the entire row when found.
Type in what you are looking for into the text box, hit search button then highlight the information in the LV

Comment: then you need a loop to look at the sub item of each LVI, if it matches add it to the SelectedItems collection by using the `Selected` property.  Highlighting is a function of the LV, as such some properties might need to be changed in the form:  `HideSelection=False`, `MultiSelect=True` and `FullRowSelect=True`.

Comment: I feel like I am on the right track for this to solving this mystery but now I get error code
Overload resolution failed because no accessible '=' can be called with these arguments:




    Private Sub Search_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Search.Click
        Dim T As String
        T = Lines.Text
        Do Until List.FocusedItem = T
            List.FocusedItem = List.Items(0)
        Loop
    End Sub

Comment: Not sure why that didnt post as code...

Comment: never post code in comments - they do not format; EDIT instead.  Are you trying to find the FIRST match only?  As before a) you need to compare the text box to the subitem.text. `FocusedItem` is a ListViewItem **object** `T` is a string - they do not compare.  b) FocusedItem is not the same as a selected item which is the org question. No idea where the error occurs, but you are going in the wrong direction.  I sense this is homework, so:  Loop thru ALL the listview items, comparing the subitem  to the text, if it matches then (again) use `Selected` prop to add it to the selected items coll.

Comment: The selected / Focus item is not necessarily important as to which is used as long as it is highlighted / visible. I edited the code a bit more think this is closer but how do I get it to start at the top and work down? this gives me another error

Comment: ...then it may matter because the FocusedItem is the one with the dotted rect around it.  that edit doesnt work (and it wasnt pasted from VS), so I am not sure why you posted it.  You said you wanted to search one of the subitems for a match, that needs to be added.  `Do` loops are a poor way to control loops; it will crash if it cant find the text.  use a `For n` loop on the LV.Items or a `For Each` loop.